# First GUI program comparing lists

Tags: java, user-interface, jbutton

I am wanting to compare lists to see if they are identical or not. Whatever the outcome may be I need to notify the user if their list compare or not. This is the first GUI I have ever done so I am still very new on how to program these. I have the textfields that I need but how can I test the user input once they select the compare button? Here is my code:

```
 JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Identical Lists");
    panel.add(lblNewLabel);

    txtEnterListOne = new JTextField();
    txtEnterListOne.setText("Enter List One: ");
    txtEnterListOne.setBounds(22, 50, 205, 24);
    contentPane.add(txtEnterListOne);
    txtEnterListOne.setColumns(10);



    int size1 = Integer.parseInt(txtEnterListOne.getText());
        int[] list1 = new int[size1];

        for (int i = 0; i < list1.length; i++) 
            list1[i] = Integer.parseInt(txtEnterListOne.getText());

    txtEnterListTwo = new JTextField();
    txtEnterListTwo.setText("Enter List Two:");
    txtEnterListTwo.setBounds(22, 107, 205, 24);
    contentPane.add(txtEnterListTwo);
    txtEnterListTwo.setColumns(10);


    int size2 = Integer.parseInt(txtEnterListTwo.getText());
    int[] list2 = new int[size2];


    for (int i = 0; i < list2.length; i++) 
      list2[i] = Integer.parseInt(txtEnterListTwo.getText());

    JButton btnCompareLists = new JButton("Compare Lists");
    btnCompareLists.setBounds(162, 162, 134, 48);
    contentPane.add(btnCompareLists);
}
     public static boolean equals(int[] list1, int[] list2) {
            if (list1.length != list2.length)
              return false;

            for (int i = 0; i < list1.length; i++) 
              if (list1[i] != list2[i])
                return false;

            return true;



     }
```

}

Comment: If you are just starting on GUI's, I'd advise moving directly to JavaFX.

Comment: use btnCompareLists.addActionListener function